# How I can calculate the percentage from between two time in Swift3?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

For example,

```
let goalTime: String = self.goalInfo![0].GoalTime
let currentTime: String = self.goalInfo![0].currentTime

print(goalTime)
print(currentTime)
```

print result:

GoalTime : 100 Hours,
CurrentTime: 75:55:56

In that case, I want show the percentage of progress.
How I can calculate between two time?

Comment: Calculate seconds of 100 hours, calculate seconds of 75:55:56. Then apply [basic math](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/proportions.html) man.

Comment: Transform both duration into seconds and do a division?

Comment: You can get the hours, minutes and seconds strings by splitting components by “:”. Then get the integer values. Better save time values as *TimeInterval* instead of strings

Comment: @emix thanks, I know that, but I got a error at dateformat

Comment: @Larme yes I got it thanks

Comment: @Carpsen90 yes it is what i want